# change text of yAxis labels in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

[image]

This line chart is drawn using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Is there any possibility to change text of labels here, ex: (69.0, 69.5, 70.0) to (bad, average, good). Or is it possible in any other chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. Take a look at the [AxisValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface) interface.

Basically that interface allows you to format the labels in any way you want, even with some kind of logic, like 50 - 100 = "good", ...

Comment: Hi Philipp, If I `setLabelCount(4); setAxisMaxValue(100);` it returns me like `0, 30, 60, 90, 100`. But I need `0, 25, 50, 75, 100`. What to do now?

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda How can i rotate the y-axis label by 90 degree in horizontal bar chart?? xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-90) will rotate the x -axis label by 90 degree.But how to rotate Y-axis label?

Comment: I want to display Y-axis values like this 5,10,15,20,25, How to do in MPAndroid library

Comment: this is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

create an arraylist of String or value types you want to replace the labels of y axis with,

`ArrayList<String> yAxisVals = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("bad", "average", "good"));`

then `lineChart.getAxisLeft().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(yAxisVals));`

will format your y axis labels.

Comment: hi, this doesnt work for me. yaxis doesnt appear after this